# Why does the object not move correctly when I press the right mouse button?

Tags: c#, 2d, movement, input, mouse

**2D Game in UNITY C#**

I have an object BULLET .

After pressing the left mouse on my object (BULLET), the script allows me to rotate object according to the mouse's direction, in four directions  :

**-up right**

**-down right**

**-down left**

**-up left**

I would like to add a movement so that the object starts moving in face direction after pressing the right mouse button.

I did it, but the object doesn't move freely in face direction and doesn't bounce off the walls, it just follows the mouse.

But I just want to fire my bullet.

I don't want the object to follow the mouse, just fire in face direction.

**You know, like an arrow from a bow.**

I press the left mouse button and I start rotate the object - **THEN I press the right mouse button and the object flies without stopping in face direction, and began to bounce off the walls.**

I show what's wrong on video (link below):
[enter link description here](https://gfycat.com/pl/gifs/detail/AlienatedBriskBarebirdbat)

This is my code:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class TestFollow : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform _bullet;
    private Vector2 _screenSize;
    private float _interval = 10;
    public Sprite sp1,sp2;
    SpriteRenderer sr;
    bool mouseClicked = false;
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float speed;
    bool rightClicked = false;


    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () 
    {
        sr = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();

        if (sr.sprite == null) // if the sprite on spriteRenderer is null then
            sr.sprite = sp1; // set the sprite to sprite1

        _bullet = transform;
        _screenSize = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height);


    }

    public void Update ()
{

    transform.position = Vector2.Lerp (transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition), moveSpeed);

    Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    difference.Normalize ();

    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Debug.Log ("Left Mouse Button was pressed");
            moveSpeed = 0f;
            if (sr.sprite == sp1) { // if the spriteRenderer sprite = sprite1 then change to sprite2
                sr.sprite = sp2;

            }
            mouseClicked = true; //register that the mouse has been clicked and the sprite is changed to sprite2
        }
    }


    if (mouseClicked) {        //checks if sprite has already been changed

        // Check for every 10 frames, reduce _interval if you want to check more often.
        if (Time.frameCount % _interval == 0) {
            // Use debug to learn mouse position, you can disable this if you want.
            Debug.Log (Input.mousePosition);

            // Mouse on Top Right screen
            _bullet.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;

            // Mouse on Bottom Right, else Mouse on Bottom Left else Mouse on Top Left
            if (Input.mousePosition.x > _screenSize.x / 2 && Input.mousePosition.y < _screenSize.y / 2)
                _bullet.Rotate (Vector3.forward, -90, Space.Self);
            else if (Input.mousePosition.x < _screenSize.x / 2 && Input.mousePosition.y < _screenSize.y / 2)
                _bullet.Rotate (Vector3.forward, -180, Space.Self);
            else if (Input.mousePosition.x < _screenSize.x / 2 && Input.mousePosition.y > _screenSize.y / 2)
                _bullet.Rotate (Vector3.forward, 90, Space.Self);
        }
    }

    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {
            Debug.Log ("Pressed secondary button.");
            rightClicked = true;
        }
        if(rightClicked)
            _bullet.transform.position += (transform.right + _bullet.transform.up).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    }
    }
}
```

PS. I'm sorry if I shouldn't post here, but I'm in a little depression. I'm working on this code for a few days and I can't change anything.

PS 2. sorry for my English. Not English-speaking country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is a bit messy, but I think you'll want to set "mouseClicked" to false when you right-click. So in the Input.GetMouseButton(1) if statement:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {
    Debug.Log ("Pressed secondary button.");
    rightClicked = true;
    mouseClicked = false;
}
```

If you then want to fire the bullet again, you'll want to add the reverse in the left-click if statement. So you'll want to set "rightClicked" to false there.

At the moment it's continuously aiming because you're never telling it to stop doing so.

**Edit:**

As you said in your comment, you want to only be able to click the left mouse button once, then ignore it.

That can be achieved by adding a new boolean to check whether or not the left mouse button can be clicked. As displayed here:

```
private bool canClick = true;

if (canClick) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Debug.Log ("Left Mouse Button was pressed");
            moveSpeed = 0f;
            if (sr.sprite == sp1) { // if the spriteRenderer sprite = sprite1 then change to sprite2
                sr.sprite = sp2;
            }
            mouseClicked = true; //register that the mouse has been clicked and the sprite is changed to sprite2

            rightClicked = false;                
            canClick = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know, I did it half an hour ago and it caused the bullet  to move as it should.
However, it create another problem:

If you press the left button again, then the ball will start following the mouse again. Can I somehow block it so that after pressing the left button again, it doesn't change anything?

Comment: Yes, you can create another boolean that also changes to false when you press the left mouse button. Then in the Input.GetMouseButton(0) if statement, you add "&& !canClick" or something along those lines.
I'll edit my answer to include this.

Comment: I will be grateful

Comment: Thank you very much.

I spent a few days on this problem, but now everything works great.

In addition, you explained what and how.

Thank you very much again.

Comment: No problem. If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to ask! But always remember to do some research by yourself first! Even just thinking about a problem enough to do the research, may lead to you finding the answer!

Comment: Ok, maybe I have one question for that.

I don't know and I don't understand why this script disables bouncing off the wall.

I added material to the wall and objects, but nothing works.

Could it be possible that the script has disabled bouncing?

Comment: Yes, because you're not using physics to move the bullet. You're basically just teleporting it a little bit on every frame when you use transform.position. If you want to be able to make it bounce, you either have to write some code that makes the bullet turn upon hitting an object, or use physics.

Comment: So I understand that I have to create a velocity based on rotation?

And adding just material will not help?

Comment: No, the materials are for the Unity physics system. If you change your code so that it uses the Unity physics system, it will work.
Or alternatively, you can create a piece of code that rotates the bullet away from an object upon impact.

Comment: Oh My God, it looks very hard and it seems to exceed my abilities. Ok, just tell me: Your "no" concerned my question about "add just material" or about "create velocity based on rotation". Because I don't know which way to go, to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, it was to both actually. Maybe this tutorial can help explain https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_p5H0wEN8Y
That tutorial works with how you've set up your code right now, but you can change it to work with physics if you want.
Then you'll want to look at this function:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html